# Return Value cannot be seen on console

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int test(int i) {
    int a = i-1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    test(3);

}
```

I am not getting returned value on console screen

Expected that the return value would be shown on console

Comment: Return value != output value. Try `return test(3);` and you will see 2 as the app exit code. Try using `std::cout` for outputting values prior app exit.

Comment: @tadman It's legal and would not raise any warning.

Comment: I have read this "the return type may not be an array type (§ 3.5, p. 113) or a function type" book: C++Primer 5th edition 2013

Comment: That quote has nothing to do with your code or question.

Comment: common beginner confusion. Returing something from a function and printing something on the console are two different things. If everytime you call a function the returned value would be printed on the screen, C++ would be pretty useless

Answer (score 2):

A quick code review:

```cpp
#include<iostream>    // Not used
#include<string>      // Not used
using namespace std;  // Bad Practice


int test(int i) {
    int a = i-1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    test(3);  // Function called, returned value discarded.
              // No code is ever called to print.

}
```

What you could do if you want to see the return value printed:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << test(3) << '\n';
}
```

This revised `main()` function will print the value returned by your `test()` function to stdout. It will utilize `<iostream>` to do so.